# Can't determine cause of CLR20r3 System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

I have some experience debugging using Problem Signatures from uncaught exceptions, but this one is confusing to me. I'm running my application on a demo laptop to show to clients. It works perfectly on my dev machine.

My application suddenly closes due to a `System.InvalidOperationException` in the `System.Core` framework assembly. I'm running the demo on a Dell Latitude E5420 With 8 GB or RAM, and Core i5-2520 @ 2.5GHz, on Windows 7 64-bit.

The problem signature looks like this

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: asi.formsetcreation.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5411d2fd
  Problem Signature 04: System.Core
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.18408
  Problem Signature 06: 5231116c
  Problem Signature 07: 43f
  Problem Signature 08: 4d
  Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidOperationException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

The Problem Signature 04 shows me that the `System.Core` assembly is throwing the exception. The Problem Signature 07 (43f) shows me that the Method was the constructor of the `System.Security.Cryptography.ECDiffieHellmanCng` class

```
.method /*0600043F*/ private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static 
        void  .cctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       0 (0x0)
} // end of method ECDiffieHellmanCng::.cctor
```

The problem signature 08 (4d) shows me the IL offset within that method, which you can see doesn't exist in the method signature above.

I have no idea what the `ECDiffieHellmanCng` class is. It is not used in my application, which is a WPF client application that makes service calls to a wcf forms processor service, and an asp.net hosted soap service.

I hooked up to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` handler, but it never handles the event, so I don't know what the stack trace of the exception is.

Is there anything else I can try to find out what is using this `ECDiffieHellmanCng` class?

Comment: Is it crashing right on startup? Double check your .config file exists. I have had issues related where the config file didn't make it or was misspelled `MyApp.config` instead of `MyApp.exe.config`. Another thing to check is that all the referenced DLLs are on your laptop. Sometimes DLLs required by a referenced DLL do not make it because they are GAC'd or located in an install folder somewhere.

Comment: It doesn't crash right on startup, but when I try to open a FormSet from my application. The logging I put in shows that the open method is running to completion but then the logging just stops and the WER screen shows up.

Comment: I am pretty sure I just figured it out though.

Comment: Just as an aside, DiffieHelman is an algorithm / procedure for exchanging cryptographic keys, which I guess would run when you try to connect with ssl or some encrypted channel. Probably doesn't help any of the above debugging, but it might help determine where in your code the above is being called from.